# PHP wont JSON encode multiple Array()'s with same name

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the structure below which I need to turn into `json_encoded`. To finally get it decoded and get an object.

This will allow me to have multiple objects with the name `message` and loop through them and process each message individually.

However when encoded, php will only encode the `key` and one of the `message` arrays—the last one.

```
$setup = [
    'key' => 'demo-7hn3fh83un3yhvfjvnjgknfhjnvf',

    'message' => [
        'number' => [
            '+39XXXXXXXX',
            '+34XXXXXXXX',
            '+49XXXXXXXX'
        ],

        'text' => 'Sample msg 123...',
    ],

    'message' => [
        'number' => [
            '+50XXXXXXXX',
            '+50XXXXXXXX'
        ],

        'text' => 'Something...',   
    ]
];
```

---

Is there a way to encode multiple arrays with the same name?

Comment: No. Even if you dumped out that structure in the PHP `print_r($setup)` you would find it has only one `message` sub-array. If there are to be multiple messages, you need to make `message` itself an array of sub structures.  Is this a structure you can modify or are you already bound to it (despite its non-functionality)?

Comment: FYI: You cannot have *duplicate* keys in an array: https://eval.in/695793

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Not bound to it. Posted the reconfigured structure as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the tips everyone. I ended up modifying the structure like below...

The reason why I am going with a structure like this is cause it allows me to submit multiple messages to multiple users with a single request.

```
$setup = [
    'key' => 'demo-7hn3fh83un3yhvfjvnjgknfhjnvf',

    'message' => [
        [
            'number' => [
                '+39XXXXXXXX',
                '+34XXXXXXXX',
                '+49XXXXXXXX'
            ],

            'text' => 'Sample msg 123...'
        ],
        [ 
            'number' => [
                '+50XXXXXXXX',
                '+50XXXXXXXX'
            ],

            'text' => 'Something...'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 3):

You've overlooked the root issue:

```
$foo = [
    'bar' => 1,
    'bar' => 2,
    'bar' => 3,
];
var_export($foo);
```

```
array (
  'bar' => 3,
)
```

Comment: Exactly, the problem has nothing to do with `json_encode`, PHP arrays do not allow two items with the same key, just just like most array/object/maps I have ever worked with.